# Viewpageindicator error, TitlePageIndicator is emty

Tags: android, android-fragments, pageviews

Hi im using viewpageindicator and have setup a viewpager and fragments that works like a charm!
The problem is that I dont seem to get the TitlePageIndicator to work. It is just empty and dosnt show anything.

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2" >

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

   <com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:linePosition="top" 
        android:theme="@style/CustomUnderlinePageIndicator"/>
```

suspect that something goes wrong with the styles. i use the style file from the viewpageindicator sample.

When i exicute this code I get following logcat error :

```
mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);

    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mIndicator = (TabPageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);
```

error: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator cannot be cast to com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator

Comment: I didn't work with this before, but I took a quick look. From what I know I think the `TitlePageIndicator` need to be inside the `ViewPager`

Comment: what do you mean by the TitlePageIndicator to be inside the ViewPager ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand you right. I thought you are using the `TitlePageIndicator` from Android support package. Anyway, please notice that you are casting TitlePageIndicator to TabPageIndicator which are not the same. It should be `(TitlePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);`. Please fix it and if it won't work we'll continue from there.

Comment: ohh, easy fix TabPageIndicator shuld be TitlePageIndicator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your XML change **TitlePageIndicator** for **TabPageIndicator** or in your file change
**mIndicator = (TabPageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);** 
for
**mIndicator = (TitlePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);**
why is it different

Answer (score 0):

use this code

mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

```
    mIndicator = (TitlePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.title_indicator);
    mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);
```